# Test cannot find application properties

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am trying to create test, that takes something from DB and compare values.

I have class and method:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class HibernateDataTest {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Test
    public void testData() {
        User u = userRepository.findByEmail("test@test.com");
        Item item = createItem(u);
        Item id =  itemRepository.save(item);
        assert(...);
    }
```

However, this keep complaining:

> Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]

I have datasource defined for hibernate, that takes properties from application.properties file.

My structure is:

```
-app
  -src/main/java
  -src/main/resources
  -src/test/java
  -src/test/resources
```

How can i link the application.properties file in this test class/method?

Thanks for help!

Comment: To take `application.properties` from main folder try add `@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` to your test class.

Comment: this throws same error

Comment: could you please sepcify the package of the test and the package of the main class (the class with @SpringBootApplication) ? If you run spring boot test like this, this kind of information becomes crucial

Answer (score 1):

Add a properties file named **'application-dev.properties'** in the following path:

```
src/test/resources
```

This should work